# Silverlight custom control default xmlns

Tags: silverlight, xaml, wpf-controls, xml-namespaces

In Silverlight, is it possible to set the default xmlns name of a custom control?

By default, each time I drag and drop one of my custom contrl on a window, the assembly and the control is automatically added to the XAML:

```
...
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyAssemblyName;assembly=MyAssemblyName"
...
<my:MyCustomControl Name="whatever"/>
```

Everthing works fine exect that I would like to replace the "my" namespace by something else (MyAssemblyName) without editing the XAML manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to control the prefix used with the `XmlnsPrefixAttribute` assembly attribute.  You would normally place this in the AssemblyInfo.cs found in the Properties folder of the project.  While you're at it you may as well add a `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` to de-couple your Xaml namespace from the assembly and .NET namespace.

```
 [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.yourorganisation.com/controls", "MyAssemblyName")]
 [assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.yourorganisation.com/controls", "myc")]
```

Now when you drop a control from the tool bar you should get:-

```
 ...
 xmlns:myc="http://schemas.yourorganisation.com/controls"
 ...

 <myc:MyCustomControl Name="whatever" />
```

You can now create multiple .NET namespaces containing controls and add multiple `XmlnsDefinition` entries in the AssemblyInfo mapping them all them to the same xml namespace and therefore the same prefix.  You can even create multiple control library projects all mapping to this same single xml namespace.

Comment: +1 for `XmlnsPrefix`. I knew about `XmlnsDefinition`,but I didnt know `XmlnsPrefix`.